# String comparision of patterns in java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

Let's say I have a string pattern as

```
/users/{id}
```

And Urls I am getting could be

```
/users/1  
/users/abc123
/users/etc
```

I mean dynamic so I have 2 variables.

```
String dynamicPathPattern = "/users/{id}";
String dynamicPath = "/users/1";

/*
 Something that will convert string pattern to regular expression. And compare it.
*/
```

Now my question is how to compare this?
I think it's is possible with regular expression. Can anyone guide please how should I start?
Is there anything readily available that I can use like `String.equals()`?

Comment: What is it you want to compare in the strings? What are you looking for?

Comment: Is your question only about the form "/users/{id}"  or are you asking about any pattern where you would use braces to describe what you want to match?

Comment: I want to compare the string that matches that pattern. And both are dynamic so I'll need to convert the pattern to regx so that I can compare it.

Comment: @ErstwhileIII any pattern in the form of braces {} like /friends/{id}/{friends_id}

Comment: Do you only have path fragments like this? Ie, no embedded `/`? Also, can there be any (encoded) spaces in arguments?

Comment: It will do you no good to use simple regex, as you need to do *variable binding*. In other words, if you use `{id}` two times in a pattern, you need to make sure it is the same value.

Comment: @fge no spaces only uri patterns

Comment: Well, you _can_ encode pretty much any Unicode character in a URI, not only spaces.

Comment: What are you trying to do (at a higher level).  That is, what form does the output of parsing such statements need to look like so you can compute whatever you are doing?  Do you simply want a list of the different variable values; a list of the variable value combinations ...?

Comment: @ErstwhileIII not like that, I want to just check whether a particular url matches the pattern or not but problem is, it is not static url both pattern and string can change.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern you are looking for would be `\{[^\{]+\}`. It searches for anything in curly brackets.

An idea would be converting your source pattern to a wrapper object, which stores the compiled pattern (escape everything except the variables) plus the name of each variable.

---

**EDIT:**
For your case, an example would look like this:

First, create a class `Range` containg two `int` for `start` and `end`. Then determine all variable ranges from `yourPatternString`:

```
Pattern variablePattern = Pattern.compile("\\{[^\\{]+\\}");
Matcher variableMatcher = variablePattern.matcher(yourPatternString);
List<Range> variableRanges = new ArrayList<>();

while(variableMatcher.find()) {
    variableRanges.add(new Range(variableMatcher.start(), variableMatcher.end()));
}
```

Now, using these ranges, you can create a new regular expression from your pattern, by replacing each range with for example `[a-zA-Z]+`. You can then simply compile a pattern and create a matcher on your input string as above.

Comment: I want it to suite for dynamic patterns.

Comment: What do you mean with "dynamic patterns"? You use the pattern i stated above to find all occurences of curly bracketed variables first. Then you generate a regular expression from your input pattern `test/hello/{example}/` which would look like `test/hello/([a-zA-Z]+)/` for example. Then you can match this expression on your input string, and get the value of each group.

Comment: ohh yes right exactly this is what I want, can you give a snippet of it that will do the generation and comparison? me too trying it.

Comment: I've edited the question and added the steps you have to take. ;) @VivekMuthal if this answered your question, please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: No this just compared the pattern. I just found the solution posting it.

Answer (score 0):

After trying a lot with regx. This is the code which satisfies all the needs. I hope so it will help others as well.

```
    String[] dynamicPathArray = dynamiPathPattern.split("/");
    String generatedPattern = "";
    for (int j = 1; j < dynamicPathArray.length; j++) {
        if (dynamicPathArray[j].contains("{")) {
            dynamicPathArray[j] = "[\\w\\s.-]+";
        } else {
            dynamicPathArray[j] = "\\b" + dynamicPathArray[j] + "\\b";
        }
        generatedPattern = generatedPattern + "/" + dynamicPathArray[j];
    }
    Pattern variablePattern = Pattern.compile(generatedPattern);
    Matcher variableMatcher = variablePattern.matcher(dynamicPath);
    if (variableMatcher.find()) {
        //Do whatever needed
    }
```